# Getting Twitter statuses from timeline via Twitter API javascript

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I need to make an http request to Twitters REST API and obtain statuses containing a certain word like "#javascript".

I looked at the docs and tried this request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#javascript
```

But I got the error: "Bad Authentication data."

Can anyone tell me how to make this request correctly?

Comment: How are you making your Javascript call?

Comment: Yes i'm using NodeJS to make the request

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Twitter require an authentication token for you to use their search api. See this page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Check this page for what you will need, and how to set it up
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview

Comment: i've added the token, it's still throwing the same error. I need an example http request to go off. The example that Twitter shows in their docs do not work. A snippet of an http request to twitter retrieving statuses from feed is what I need.

Comment: How did you assemble the token? Check out this link from the OAuth site about creating http requests   http://nouncer.com/oauth/authentication.html